# "... not only does it ..." vs. "... not only it ..."?

Tags: expressions

What structure the two following expressions follow? More specific, what is the role of "**does**" in the first expression?

1. *This is mainly because not only **does** it positively affect students' opinions, but it also ... .*
2. *This is mainly because not only it positively affect students' opinions, but it also ... .*

Does the removal of "**does**" in the second structure make it wrong. If not, what is the first one is benefitted from "**does**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. This is mainly because not only **does** it positively affect students' opinions, but it also ... .
> 2. This is mainly because not only it positively affect students' opinions, but it also ... .

The “does” is required to put the subject after “not only”. Without it, you must use the standard word order:

> This is mainly because **it** not only positively **affects** students' opinions, but it also ... .

Notice that without “do” as a helper verb, “affect” changes from bare infinitive to present simple. Since the subject is “it”, that means “-s”.